# Make numbered list item a member of previous item with a new sub-level list in the middle

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, text-formatting

I have a numbered list using a custom defined format of which I am utilizing several levels throughout the document.

Here is an example of what I am getting:

```
    A. List item A
        1. List item 1
            a. List item a
            b. List item b
        2. Continuing List item 1
        3. List item 2
```

I'd like to have item `2.` be a part of `1.` and have item `3.` actually be item `2.`.

Here is the result that I am looking to get:

```
    A. List item A
        1. List item 1
            a. List item a
            b. List item b
           Continuing List item 1
        2. List item 2
```

I'm not sure of the technical terms I'd use to search the Internet on how to describe what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I got this to work step-by-step:

1. Manually type "**A.**" on first line in Word and pressed <kbd>**Space**</kbd> and it automatically indented and then I typed in "**List item**" to the right of that.
2. I then pressed <kbd>**Enter**</kbd> to go to the next line where it made it "**B.**" and then to the right of "**B.**" I typed in "**1.**" to it looked like "**B. 1.**" and then clicked in the spot just left of the "**1**" character and pressed <kbd>**<= Backspace**</kbd> one time to get just "**1.**" so I typed in "**List item**" to the right of that.

[image]

3. I then pressed <kbd>**Enter**</kbd> to get "**2.**" on the next line and I wrote "**List item**".

[image]

4. Then I clicked in the spot just to the right of "**1. List Item**" where I just pressed <kbd>**Enter**</kbd> and then pressed <kbd>**Tab**</kbd> to get "**a.**". I typed in "**List item**" to the right of that and pressed <kbd>**Enter**</kbd> again to get "**b.**" on the next line where I also typed in "**Continuing List Item 1**".

[image]

5. Finally I clicked in the spot just to the left "**Continuing List Item 1**" and pressed <kbd>**<= Backspace**</kbd> to get the needed format.

[image]

Just follow those steps moving forward to scale further.

---

See the updated screen shots below after further testing since question was updated and since further comments clarified:

**Comments:**

> - This is an excellent answer! However, I think you need to hit Backspace once more to bring the `Continuing List Item 1` back in-line
>     with the a.? – [mjsqu](https://superuser.com/users/525891/mjsqu)
> - I have updated the examples to provide more clarification – [вʀaᴎᴅᴏƞ
>     вєнᴎєƞ](https://superuser.com/users/391452/%D0%B2%CA%80a%E1%B4%8E%E1%B4%85%E1%B4%8F%C6%9E-%D0%B2%D1%94%D0%BD%E1%B4%8E%D1%94%C6%9E)
> - Can you not just go ahead and create **A.** followed by **1., 2,., 3., and so on...** and then follow the instructions as I listed above to build the format that way for the other sub-items and then beside 2. just to the left of it, press backspace once and then suddenly it's number goes away and 3. turns into 2.. I'm doing this all in Word 2013 on Windows 10 and I'm getting the results you expect and need from
>     what I can tell, but as **mjsqu** pointed out, you could press
>     **Backspace twice in #5 to take it down a line and over to the left a tad.** –
>     [PIMP_JUICE_IT](https://superuser.com/users/510662/pimp-juice-it)
> - I updated my answer with a couple screen shots with Word 2013 on my PC as per the above comment instructions to show you so take a look at
>     it when you get a chance. If that does it for you, I will update my
>     answer but you can see in **2. List Item 3** so this is where it was
>     **3. List Item 3** before I pressed **Backspace** as mentioned in the comment I wrote above this comment.. –
>     [PIMP_JUICE_IT](https://superuser.com/users/510662/pimp-juice-it)

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is an excellent answer! However, I think you need to hit Backspace once more to bring the `Continuing List Item 1` back in-line with the `a.`?

Comment: When I press backspace on Step 5, the text is moved back a level which creates the formatting of the first example in my question. Also the `Continuing List Item 1` line needs to be indented the same as item `1. ` as in my second example.

Comment: I have updated the examples to provide more clarification

Answer (score 2):

When hitting enter after `b. List item` you should be able to hit <kbd>Backspace</kbd> a couple of times and the cursor should return in-line with the `a.` and `b.`. Technically this text will be in 'Normal' format, and won't actually be a part of the list, so I'm aware this may only answer the question from an aesthetic point of view.

If you're typing out the list from the top and not just editing an existing list, you might now turn your numbering style back on, and find it goes back to `A`, if that happens you can right click on the number and get it to 'Continue Numbering' to force it to pick up from where you last left off.

It can help to go to View and turn on the Ruler setting, this shows where the tab-stops are.

It's also worth noting that you can play with the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Tab</kbd> keys to move text up and down through the list-levels, which might help if you suddenly find text has become divorced from the list.